# Encrypting hypelinkfields in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I need to encrypt the Url's in my web application. I followed Mads Kristensen's (http://madskristensen.net/post/HttpModule-for-query-string-encryption.aspx) article for  encrypting Urls. It is working perfectly. However, I have hyperlinkfield in a gridview for which I am using datanavigateurlformatstring and datanavigateurlfields properties to create the query string e.g

```
  <asp:HyperLinkField Text="Edit" datanavigateurlfields="DocumentId"
            datanavigateurlformatstring="~\admin\edit_document.aspx?DocumentId={0}"  />
```

When the hyperlinks are clicked, the link opens and the urls are encrypted. However, if I hover my mouse over the hyperlinks, I can see data in the query string with no encryption. Any idea how to encrypt the query string when the mouse is hovered over the hyperlink?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the `HyperLinkField` is generating the `<a>` tag with the unencrypted arguments, as well as a "title" attibute that matches the unencrypted version.  Then your module kicks in (after the html is generated) and changes the `href` attibute, but leaves the `title` attribute intact.

Try setting the `title` attibute explicitly, if that doesn't work, you might need to subclass the `HyperLinkField` class to override that functionality.

You can inspect the generated source of your page to verify this.